# Is polynomial ring of n variables with coefficients in an arbitrary valuation ring coherent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I was wondering if for an arbitrary valuation ring $R$ and an element $\pi$ in the maximal ideal of $R$, the rings

1. $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$;
2. projective limit of $R/(\pi^l)[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, probably also denoted as $R \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$ in the case when $R$ is a rank 1 valuation ring and;
3. $R/(\pi)[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

are coherent or not?

The obvious implication being that either (1) or (2) would imply (3), and I think in the rank 1 valuation case all three rings considered above are indeed coherent. But I really don't know anything about this question in general. Any comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concerning question (1):

> Polynomial algebras in finitely many indeterminates over valuation domains are coherent.

This is Theorem 7.3.3 in S. Glaz, *Commutative coherent rings,* Springer LNM 1371 (1989).